# 5.1 to mono using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I have mp4 file with audio 5.1 that I want to make to mono as default using FFmpeg.

Here is the codec information:

```
 Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 01:59:51.99, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 2450 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2317 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

My goal is to keep the video as it is and make the audio to mono as default, the output codec for audio should be

```
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
```

I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i "my_file.mp4" -strict -2 -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

You specified `-c:a copy` in your command, which will just copy the audio stream without transformation. `-map` also only selects **streams**. A audio **stream** in a video container is for example a second language, or commentator track.

What you are looking for is something to convert the **channels** of the audio.

---

According to the [ffmpeg documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) you can downmix the audio channels with the `-ac <channels>` flag.

[image: 5.1 to stereo]

```
ffmpeg -i 6channels.wav -ac 2 stereo.wav
```

This example would convert a surround file to stereo. But we want mono audio.

---

[image: stereo to mono]

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.flac -ac 1 mono.flac
```

It seems that specifying `-ac 1` should get the desired result in one pass.

---

### Example:

Start with a video with 5.1 audio channel:

```
$- mediainfo output_surround.mkv
...
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 384 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel layout                           : L R C LFE Ls Rs
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
...
```

Run `ffmpeg` with the options we discovered over it:

```
ffmpeg -i output_surround.mkv  -c:v copy -ac 1 output_mono.mkv
```

You are left with a mono audio channel file:

```
$- mediainfo output_mono.mkv
...
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 80.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
...
```